# How do I run through PDF files in a path, format and clean each one, and spit out regex with specific text from the individual files?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pdf

I have a script that takes a PDF and formats it to HTML, cleans up the HTML tags and spits out a clean text.  Then runs some regex to extract data from each PDF.  Basically I'm having trouble figuring out how to iterate through all the files and run the cleanup, THEN run regex for each.  My code looks something like this:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import HTMLConverter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from cStringIO import StringIO
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import glob
import re

path = r'F:\Desktop\Metadata\'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.pdf")
for file_ in allFiles:
    convert_pdf_to_html(file_)

def convert_pdf_to_html(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = HTMLConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec = codec, laparams = laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages = maxpages, password = password, caching = caching, check_extractable = True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return str
```

Now here is the part I'm confused about.  I have to set the convert_pdf_to_html as a variable such as "text" and then take that text and input it through beautiful soup to clean it up.  I need to do this for each PDF file in my folder.

```
text = convert_pdf_to_html(path)
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')  #remove HTML tags
document_text = soup.get_text()     #cleaned up text
```

Then I need to run a few regex queries like so and output them each to a new file with the format 'filename.csv'

```
print " Alt : "
list = (re.findall(r"""
    ((?:LE|BA|BE|BM|BC)[\w]+\:)
    """,document_text, re.X))

print list
```

Comment: Notice how all the code in your question following the `path = r'F:\Desktop\Metadata\'` line is shown red by the syntax highlighter, like it's part of the string constant? That's because you can't end a raw string with a backslash character. I suggest you use forward slashes in the path, or better yet, use the `os.path.join()` to concatenate the pathname components together rather than `+`.

Answer (score 0):

The good way will be create a class which can handle each of your function for each instance of file you send to the class.

```
Class PDFParser:
    file = ''
    def __init__(self, myfile):
          file = myfile

    def get_html_response(self):
        //your code for pdf to html

    def run_regx(self):
        //run your regex here.

for file_ in allFiles:
    my_parse = PDFParser(file_)
    my_parse.get_html_response()
    my_parse.run_regx()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! in the def get_html_response do I put the full def convert_pdf_to_html inside it?  Or did you just rename it to get_html_response?

Comment: yeah. I just renamed the name. You can have your function and call it using your instance.

Comment: @staten12, and please don't forget to vote, if it is useful :)

Comment: I've created the class, however i'm running into errors now due to the file paths within my pdf_to_html function

Comment: @staten12, 
Path is working well in Linux. I think you need to use '\' in your allFiles, isn't ?
>>> path = '/home/sijan/Desktop/'
>>> allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.py")
>>> allFiles
['/home/sijan/Desktop/emailread.py', '/home/sijan/Desktop/test3.py', '/home/sijan/Desktop/test.py']